# How to produce single updates when batch editing in dynamic data

Tags: c#, dynamic-data

Let me start by saying that I'm really new to both Reactive Extensions and [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData) so i'm probably missing something really obvious here.

Aim:
I want to calculate the profit (or loss) for some trades (similar to: https://dynamic-data.org/2014/11/22/trading-example-part-2-manage-market-data/) based on the new market prices.
For simplicity lets say that all prices received in the last second are considered new.

My problem: Multiple update events occur for the same currencies in 1 sec (eg EURUSD) even if batch editing is used. Ideally i would only like to raise 1 event based on the latest available value to avoid doing unnecessary calculations.

My code so far:

Main.cs

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using DynamicData;


TickService tickService = new();

tickService.NewTicks
    .Connect()
    .Watch("EURUSD")
    .Subscribe(price => Console.WriteLine(price));

/*
 * In the actual project the prices come from an external system,
 * but that is irrelevant here 
 * so for the sake of simplicity I'm adding them manually (with a delay)
 * to TickService
 */
Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var newTicks = new List<Tick>() { new Tick() { Name = "EURUSD", Price = i, LastUpdate = DateTime.UtcNow } };
        tickService.AddTicks(newTicks);
        Console.WriteLine($"Added: i -> {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Tick.cs

```
public class Tick
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name}, Price: {Price}, LastUpdate: {LastUpdate}";
    }
}
```

TickService.cs (Exposes an IObservableCache with the prices of the last second)

```
using DynamicData;

public class TickService
{
    private readonly SourceCache<Tick, string> _ticksCache = new(x => x.Name);
    public IObservableCache<Tick, string> NewTicks { get; }

    public TickService()
    {
        NewTicks = _ticksCache
             .Connect()
             .Filter(tick => tick.LastUpdate > DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
             .Batch(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
             .AsObservableCache();
    }

    public void AddTicks(ICollection<Tick> newTicks)
    {
        _ticksCache.Edit(innerCache => innerCache.AddOrUpdate(newTicks));
    }
}
```

The above code results in the below result:

```
Added: i -> 0
Added: i -> 1
Added: i -> 2
Added: i -> 3
Add, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 0, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:20 pm, Previous: <None>
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 1, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:20 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 0, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:20 pm
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 2, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 1, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:20 pm
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 3, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 2, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm
Added: i -> 4
Added: i -> 5
Added: i -> 6
Added: i -> 7
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 4, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 3, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 5, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 4, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 6, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 5, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 7, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 6, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm
Added: i -> 8
Added: i -> 9
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 8, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 7, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 9, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 8, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm
```

What i want is:

```
Added: i -> 0
Added: i -> 1
Added: i -> 2
Added: i -> 3
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 3, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 2, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:21 pm
Added: i -> 4
Added: i -> 5
Added: i -> 6
Added: i -> 7
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 7, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 6, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm
Added: i -> 8
Added: i -> 9
Update, Key: EURUSD, Current: Name: EURUSD, Price: 9, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm, Previous: Name: EURUSD, Price: 8, LastUpdate: 14/03/2022 4:14:22 pm
```

Since i'm using batch editing I would expect only one one update event to produce every second for EURUSD. Any ideas/advice as to what I'm missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a long standing request by several people which has never materialized into an operator, so I've added a new operator to Dynamic Data to achieve uniqueness within a change set notification.

New operator is called `EnsureUniqueKeys` which can be applied to a cache

```cs
    var uniqueChanges = _myCache.Connect().EnsureUniqueKeys()
```

where

```cs
    _myCache.Edit(innerCache =>
    {
        innerCache.AddOrUpdate(new Person("Me", 20));
        innerCache.AddOrUpdate(new Person("Me", 21));
        innerCache.AddOrUpdate(new Person("Me", 22));
    });
```

will produce a single Add notification for  Person("Me", 22)

and

```cs
  _myCache.Edit(innerCache =>
    {
        innerCache.AddOrUpdate(new Person("Me", 20));
        innerCache.AddOrUpdate(new Person("Me", 21));
        innerCache.RemoveKey("Me");
    });
```

Will produce an empty change set because the item is added, updated and removed in the same edit.

The operator can be applied in the TickService as such:

```cs
 NewTicks = _ticksCache
        .Connect()
        .Filter(tick => tick.LastUpdate > DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Batch(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .EnsureUniqueKeys()      
        .AsObservableCache();
```

Comment: I leave a link to the github discussion were it contains the PR and other information in case anyone needs this in the future. https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData/discussions/570
@Roland Pheasant Thank you for your help